# Changing focus from on textbox to another, when tabpages is changed in C#?

Tags: c#, focus, tabcontrol, enter, tabpage

I have several tabs in a form. Each tab has one textbox. When I enter tabpage1 I have managed to set the focus on the textBox1. When I press a button in tabpage1 I jump to a random tab in the controller. What I want now is to have the focus set on textBox in the active tabpage. I have tried using tabpage_Enter event, but it does not seem to work. My code look like this :

```
    private void tabPage2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Select();

    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use SelectedIndexChanged event of TabControl instead of _Enter, using Enter event, focus will change to textBox2  every time the cursor enter the tabPage control.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with this code : tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
switch (tabControl.SelectedIndex)
{
case 0: textBox1.Focus();
break;
case 1: textBox2.Focus();
break;
// 
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Focus() method set the focus on a textbox. I would probably set on the tabPage_Enter event.

```
private void tabPage_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
{
    var tab = sender as tabPage;
    if(!tab.Focused) tab.focus();
}
```

Comment: I have tried textBox2.Focus() also. I won´t work. Why should I use var tab = sender as tabPage etc?

Comment: var tab = sender as tabPage makes the code generic for all tabs that get assigned tabPage_Enter as an event. This way you do not have to write an individual event for each tab